# Why is my SVG not scaling same size as parent DIV?

Tags: css, svg

I want my svg image to be the exact same size as the parent div, i tried doing it as a background image also but its not working.

[This is the example of a screnshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEBPW.jpg)

```
      <div className='contact'>
        <div  className='contact-splash'>
          <img src='path/astro.svg' alt=""/>
      </div>
```

```
.contact {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 7%;
    font-family: Oswald;
}

.contact-splash {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;

    img {
        max-height: 80vh;
        max-width: 100%; 
        width: auto; 
        height: auto; 
        position: absolute; 
        margin: auto;
    }

}
```

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1400px" height="1100px" viewBox="0 0 1400 1100" enable-background="new 0 0 1400 1100" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="1400" height="1100" x="0" y="0"
```

Comment: Can you please provide the svg?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image tag in the same size as the Div contact, just specify `height:100%; width:100%;` inside image style instead of `max-height: 80vh; max-width: 100%;`